# Changing email "From" address

Tags: email

So, I have been trying to set up "reply-to" in the order email.

I have few ideas to do it. Here is one of them.

Following is admin option to set up "From" email address

```
    array(
            'title'             => __( '"From" Email Address', 'woocommerce' ),
            'desc'              => '',
            'id'                => 'woocommerce_email_from_address',
            'type'              => 'email',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'multiple' => 'multiple'
            ),
            'css'               => 'min-width:300px;',
            'default'           => get_option( 'admin_email' ),
            'autoload'          => false
        ),
```

As you can see, the default value is `admin_email`.

I am trying to change it to `billing_email` from the order

```
<?php echo $order->billing_email; ?>
```

In this method (if works), then all the order email will be "sent" from the customer's email (`billing_email`) instead of `admin_email`. Therefore the recipient can reply directly to that `billing_email` instead of `Admin_email`.

How can I change the `default` value to `billing_email`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'woocommerce_email_settings' filter is what you need.

```
function prefix_change_from_email( $args ) {    
    global $wpo_wcpdf;
    for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $args ); $i++ ) {
        if( 'woocommerce_email_from_address' == $args[ $i ]['id'] ) {
            $args[ $i ]['default'] = $wpo_wcpdf->billing_email();
            return $args;
        }
    }       
    return $args; // just in case
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_settings', 'prefix_change_from_email', 15 );
```

Comment: So, I used the function above to change the default value. But it looks like there is a plugin that overwrites them. Now, I am thinking of editing that plugin so I can change the default value. Would you be able to take a look at the post? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183294/change-default-from-email-address-continue